# Treat merged cells as one

Tags: vba, excel

I am using a VBA code in excel to export a selected range to a text file, but when I use merged cells(merged rows), I get added blank rows in my export. How do I make the code treat merged cells as one?

```
Sub writeCSV(ByVal thisRange As Range, ByVal filePath As String, Optional ByVal fileAppend As Boolean = False)
Dim cLoop As Long, rLoop As Long
Dim ff As Long, strRow As String

ff = FreeFile
If fileAppend Then
    Open filePath For Append As #ff
Else
    Open filePath For Output As #ff
End If

For rLoop = 1 To thisRange.Rows.Count
    strRow = ""
    For cLoop = 1 To thisRange.Columns.Count
        If cLoop > 1 Then strRow = strRow & ","
        strRow = strRow & thisRange.Cells(rLoop, cLoop).Value
    Next 'cLoop
    Print #ff, strRow
Next 'rLoop

Close #ff
End Sub

Sub Wri()

Dim myrng As Range
Dim Cell As Range

On Error Resume Next
Set myrng = Application.InputBox("Select range", Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0

If myrng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "No cells selected"
    Exit Sub
Else
    writeCSV myrng, "C:\Users\HP\Documents\fil.txt", True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It's difficult to imagine exactly how you'd want that to behave: what if only part of a row is merged, or parts of multiple rows are merged.

Comment: unmerge than merge back?

Comment: Could one use the cell address of the topmost cell in the chosen range and ignore the others, the others will all be part of the merging and will be 0?